# Display images stored in a database without using header

Tags: php, mime-types, content-type

I like the photo that I keep stored in my view using the following code but the problem is I can not play because I need the `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` implementation would then display., But I have orders sure before `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` What should I do to display images with no header.

Comment: why not use <img> tag?

Comment: Redirect directly to the image.

Comment: Tell us, please, the schema or how could store your images in the database?

Answer (score 2):

If you're only outputting the image, then it doesn't matter if you have other PHP instructions before it since the only output should be the image.

If you are trying to output an image directly into an HTML document, consider using a data URI:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($imagedata); ?>" />
```